# Desktop sharing on Lync SDK , Application Modality returns null

Tags: sdk, desktop, lync

On the click of a button  the desktop sharing event should be triggered for the active conversation window. In the button click we have the following code :

```
      private void StartSharingResource_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //If there is no active conversation to share this resource in, return from handler
            if (_conversation == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            //If there is no sharing modality stored locally on the active conversation, get it from the active conversation and store it.
            if (_sharingModality == null)
            {
                _sharingModality = _conversation.Modalities[ModalityTypes.ApplicationSharing] as ApplicationSharingModality;
            }

        }
```

On Conversation Added even we are fetching the conversation modality

```
void ConversationManager_ConversationAdded(object sender, Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ConversationManagerEventArgs e)
        {
          _sharingModality = (ApplicationSharingModality)_conversation.Modalities[ModalityTypes.ApplicationSharing];

}
```

In both the section _conversation.Modalities[ModalityTypes.ApplicationSharing] is coming as null and we get an object reference error. We are using LYNC SDK - 15.0.4603.1000 version.

Answer (score 0):

You Lync SDK version is higher than your Lync client version, so some api calls are not guaranteed. Please apply the latest Lync patch from [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn788954.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).